# Thunderbird in a new computer: will it download old emails?

Tags: thunderbird, imap

I would like to install Thunderbird in a new computer, and give it an IMAP account.

This IMAP account has 3000+ emails, and I would rather keep them at bay in the server, and receive only the new ones - from today onwards.

Would that be possible, or am I forced to download all the old stuff?

Thanks,

Comment: Why not copy the whole profile over?

Comment: Searching using google "thunderbird imap only download last year", second result gave me: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1066286 -1 from me for not taking any effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two good options, the one you asked for and the one Daniel B suggested in his comment:

- In the account settings of the IMAP account there should be a point "Synchronization & Storage" under which you may define until which age older messages may be fetched from the server.
- You can also just copy everything over. See this mozilla support entry, which definitely has appeared on this site already:https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-thunderbird-stores-user-data#w_restoring-to-a-different-location

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to put your older emails in a different folder and just sync the inbox. You would then know that you have all the emails from today forth.
I'm pretty sure Thunderbird had the option to sync specific folders.